# Express Router - uploading to S3 and MongoDb

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, router, multer

I'm trying to do the following in Node.js using express router, Multer-S3, Multer, AWS and Mongodb.

I want to:
1: Check if filetype is image, price is number etc (some kind of quality check)
2: If above true, upload image to S3 to get Image url
3: If Image Url was generated, upload to Mongodb, including the generated image url..

Trying with below code but can only get one of these to work at same time..

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const shopController = require("../controllers/shop");

router.post(
  "/shop/create/:shopId",
  shopController.creatingShop,
  shopController.createShopItem
);
```

```
const ShopItem = require("../models/shopitem"); //Mongoose Schema

const multer = require("multer");
const fileview = multer().single("file1"); //Trying to use this to view file before uploading to S3

const uploader = require("../services/file-upload");
const singleUpload = uploader.single("file1"); //Using this to upload to S3

exports.createShopItem = (req, res, next) => {
  fileview(req, res, function (err) {
    const file = req.file;
    const title = req.body.title;
    const price = req.body.price;
    const description = req.body.description;
    const location = req.body.location;
    const user = "OrreSnorre";

    if (
      file.mimetype != "image/jpeg" &&
      file.mimetype != "image/jpg" &&
      file.mimetype != "image/png"
    ) {
      return next(new Error("invalid file type"));
    }

    if (file.size > 2500000) {
      return next(new Error("Your image is to big. Maximum 2.5mb"));
    }
    next();
    console.log(
      "Here I want to add upload text to mongoDb... including URL from S3 after it is generated"
    );
   
  });

exports.creatingShop = (req, res, next) => {
  singleUpload(req, res, function (err) {
    console.log(req.file);
    // res.json({ "image-url": req.file.location });
  });
  next();
};
```

Anyone got ideas? Or examples that work?

Best regards,
Oscar

Comment: Are you using multer s3? and what is the logic behind `uploader`

Comment: Hi, yeah, trying to use multer... Logic is like this:

Comment: const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");
require("dotenv").config();

aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: my key,
  accessKeyId: my key,
  region: "eu-north-1",
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();

const uploader = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: "shopitemimages",
    acl: "public-read",
    contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
    
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString());
    },
  }),
});

module.exports = uploader;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this, either you can use only `multer` or `multer-s3`.

For simplicity, I will show you the way using only `multer`.

Flow of processing as follow:

1. Multer process and save to local
2. You read from local, and upload to s3 using s3 SDK (You should explore how to remove the file after upload as well, but I wont clutter you with this logic here)
3. If upload is successful, you retrieve the URL and pass it to your MongoDB.

```
    // Make "temp" directory as multer.diskStorage wont create folder
    fs.mkdir('./temp', { recursive: true }, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
    const PORT = parseInt(process.argv[2]) || parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 3000;
    // Multer
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './temp');
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        let extArray = file.mimetype.split('/');
        let extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
        cb(null, new Date().getTime() + '.' + extension);
      },
    });
    
    const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
    
    const endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(AWS_S3_HOSTNAME);
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
      endpoint,
      accessKeyId: AWS_S3_ACCESSKEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESSKEY,
    });
    
    // Get the uploaded file in local here
    const readFile = (path) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        fs.readFile(path, (err, buff) => {
          if (null != err) reject(err);
          else resolve(buff);
        })
    
    // Upload to AWS S3 here
    const putObject = (file, buff, s3) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const params = {
          Bucket: AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
          Key: file.filename,
          Body: buff,
          ACL: 'public-read',
          ContentType: file.mimetype,
          ContentLength: file.size,
        };
        s3.putObject(params, (err, result) => {
          if (null != err) reject(err);
          else resolve(file.filename);
        });
      });
      );
    
    const mongoClient = new MongoClient(MONGO_URL, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    app.post('/api/post', upload.single('imageFile'), async (req, res) => {
    readFile(req.file.path)
            .then((buff) =>
              // Insert Image to S3 upon succesful read
              putObject(req.file, buff, s3)
            )
            .then((results) => {
              // build url of the resource upon successful insertion
              const resourceURL = `https://${AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME}.${AWS_S3_HOSTNAME}/${results}`;
              const doc = {
                comments,
                title,
                ts: new Date(),
                image: resourceURL, // Your URL reference to image here
              };
              // Insert to your mongoDB
              mongoClient
                .db(MONGO_DB)
                .collection(MONGO_COLLECTION)
                .insertOne(doc)
                .then((results) => {
                  // delete the temp file when no error from MONGO & AWS S3
                  fs.unlink(req.file.path, () => {});
                  // return the inserted object
                  res.status(200).json(results.ops[0]);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.error('Mongo insert error: ', error);
                  res.status(500);
                  res.json({ error });
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error('insert error: ', error);
              res.status(500);
              res.json({ error });
            });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Not fully familiar with the code, will give it a try this afternoon! Been struggeling with this for 10 mornings/evenings..!

Comment: Feel free to ask if you're not sure what the code is doing. This is sort of like my template when doing something with S3 and multer

Comment: Hi again, struggling some more with this.. I was just having one last look at the original code..   router.post(
  "/shop/create/:shopId",
  shopController.createShopItem, 
  shopController.creatingShop //if this middleware is first in the middlewares, it works and the req.file is something else than when it's second.. 
); I get a different req.file / req.body depending on the order of the middleware? Do you know any reason to this?

Comment: The middleware that is working with multer have to be the before you actually access to `req.file`. 

But I still can't see how you're uploading to s3 using `singleUpload `

Comment: Hi again! Some more fighting with this code (I have never spent this amount of time per line) It seems your comment here - having the multer before - is helping me further! I think my issue is trying to use a second multer middleware, it has then not been working properly for some reason... Thanks a lot for your kind assistance!